# Equation "solved through" or "solved by"?

Tags: mathematics

Which one is better?

> - "The equation *x² = 4* is **solved through** *2* and *-2*."
> - "The equation *x² = 4* is **solved by** *2* and *-2*."

Which other suggestions do you have?

Just by googling, I could not resolve this problem...

Comment: This suggests solved by https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=solved+through%2Csolved+by&year_start=1980&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csolved%20through%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csolved%20by%3B%2Cc0 - if you run the function over  a range of numbers it would be _The equation is run from -2 through 2_

Comment: The equation  x² = 4 has the solutions 2 and -2.

Comment: "The equation x² = 4 is satisfied by x = -2 and x = 2." //
"The equation x² = 4 has the roots -2 and 2."

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful comments. I have increased the complexity of my question a bit in a comment given to bsink's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two, I personally think "solved by" sounds better.

The comments on your question provide some excellent alternatives as well. "has the solutions/roots" and "is satisfied by" are great, though I would prefer the former if you're supplying the full list of possible solutions as the latter could be ambiguous. E.g. "x²=4 is satisfied by x=2" is completely accurate, although it doesn't provide all possible roots to the quadratic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Could you help me with something like "The equation system *a + b = 2*, *2b = 2* is successively solved in *a* and *b* by *b = 1*, *a = 2 - b = 2 - 1 = 1*" (seems to be a little bit more constructed, but I have this construction in a more complex context)? Should it be **"by a applying"**, **"through"** or something else?